# return value when count equals variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case

I have a table to update with other table data. For this I created a trigger. Inside trigger, I must check how many **active** occurrences of each `id`. If this number of occurrences is same number than a variable value then return `1 (true)` otherwise `0 (false)`.

I get the variable

```
DECLARE @num_gerencias numeric(2, 0)
SELECT @num_gerencias = (SELECT COUNT(id_gerencia) FROM FR_GERENCIES)
select @num_gerencias
```

This works ok... returns `5`

Then, I make a count of occurrences of the `l_activo` variable in other table (variable is a `bit`):

```
SELECT id_operacio, SUM(CASE WHEN l_activo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                FROM FR_GERENCIES_OPERACIONS o 
                GROUP BY o.id_operacio
```

This query also works nice, returns:

```
2958    5
2959    0
2960    5
2961    3
2962    5
2963    5
2964    2
2965    4
2966    5
2967    5
```

All perfect... now i must get same list, but if sum equals to `@num_gerencias`, then put 1 and 0 otherwise.

**Expected result table**

```
2958    1
2959    0
2960    1
2961    0
2962    1
2963    1
2964    0
2965    0
2966    1
2967    1
```

I've tried with `CASE`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_operacio, CASE WHEN 
            (
                SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN l_activo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                FROM FR_GERENCIES_OPERACIONS o 
                GROUP BY o.id_operacio
            ) = @num_gerencias THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

but I'm getting error:

> Mens . 512 , Level 16 , State 1, Line 6
>   The subquery returned more than one value , which is not correct when it goes below = , ! = , <, < = ,>, > = Or when used as an expression .

I also tried with an `IF` (i guess this option is totally wrong for this case... but I've tried)

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_operacio,
    IF @num_gerencias = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN l_activo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            FROM FR_GERENCIES_OPERACIONS o 
            GROUP BY o.id_operacio) 
    1
    ELSE 0
FROM FR_GERENCIES_OPERACIONS
```

But I have syntax errors...

Any idea how can i reach **expected result table**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there, however your grouping and selection must occur outside of your case statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id_operacio
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(CAST(l_activo AS INTEGER)) = @num_gerencias THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM FR_GERENCIES_OPERACIONS o 
GROUP BY o.id_operacio
```

Comment: it complains that `bit` cannot be used in `sum`

Comment: Cast the bit to an integer with `CAST(l_activo AS INTEGER)`

Comment: sweet answer.... really smart to use the `bit` value instead inner `CASE` thanks for your help @Wibbler :)